# using downgradeComponent for a component in angular[ng2] for services and controller in angularjs

Tags: angular, angular2-upgrade

I have downgraded many Angular[Ng2] based components and used them in AngularJS application, so ideally a statement like below works perfectly -

```
angular.module('com.myservicemodule').service("overviewService", upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Provider(OverviewComponent));
```

Here OverviewComponent is a Angular[NG2] component and i have downgraded it and added to my AngularJS module "com.myservicemodule".So final AngularJs bootstraped application do run time execution like below for these dependencies-

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['com.myservicemodule']) .run('$rootScope', '$q','$window','$location','OverviewComponent', function($q, $window,$location,OverviewComponent){// Some app code});
```

But now i have an hybrid app which bootstrap with x number of dependencies and some of these dependencies are a downgraded version of Angular[NG2] component.

And start getting ng2.injector issues as if these components are not downgraded on time for angularjs.

I tried with latest way of using downgrade Angular[Ng2] components like-

```
import {UpgradeModule} from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
export const upgradeAdapter = platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
  return platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule);  
});
```

And then downgrade the Angular[NG2] component to a directive like -

```
downgradeComponent({component: OverviewComponent}) as angular.IDirectiveFactory
```

but using this it seems i get only directive in angularJs 1.X. So anyone know how to get service,controllers counterparts?